# How to determine if $\{n \cdot g^a \mod P\}$ and $\{m \cdot g^a \mod P\}$ generate the same sets? (set size < $P-1$)

Tags: cryptanalysis, discrete-logarithm

given some examples $k_{n_i},k_{m_i}$ out  of each value set:
$k_{n_i} \in \{n \cdot g^a \mod P\, \forall a \in \mathbb{N}<P\}=G_m$
$k_{m_i} \in \{m \cdot g^a \mod P, \forall a \in \mathbb{N}<P\}=G_n$

Each set has size of $S$ which is a prime and known. Value $P$ is also a prime with $P = 2 \cdot S \cdot f+1$. Factor $f$ is (product of) prime(s) which is known as well. The Generator $g$ is known too. For a given $k$ the factors $n,m$ and related exponent $a$ is unknown.

As shown [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/70335/is-there-a-fast-way-to-solve-k-n-cdot-ga-mod-p-get-a-for-unknown-n) for each $k$ multiple value pairs $(n,a)$ can be computed very fast (pick an $a$ and compute $n=kg^{-a} \mod P$). That means those sets can be equal with $n\not=m$.
Now is there a way to check if they generate the same sets (without computing all combinations?)

Comment: For what set is $g$ a generator?

Comment: same $g$ used in both sets, only the factor is different. $g^S = 1 \mod P$ and $P=2Sf+1$. So $g$ is not a prime root of $P$. It can only generate a subgroup of size $S$. With two different factors $m,n$ it generates two sets with all elements equal or 0 of them. With all possible factors $n'$ a total of $2 \cdot f$ sets can get generated, which don't contain equal elements and all numbers from $1$ to $P-1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$G_n = G_m$ iff $n^S \equiv m^S \pmod P$

Proof:

If $n^S \not\equiv m^S \pmod P$, then $\forall e \in G_n : e^S = n^S$ (as $e^S = n^S \cdot (g^a)^s = n^S$); and similarly $\forall f \in G_m : f^S = m^S$.  Hence $\forall e \in G_n, f \in G_m: e \ne f$, and hence $G_n \ne G_m$ (and actually the two sets are disjoint).

Other direction (needed because we're asserting equivalence):

If $n^S \equiv m^S \pmod P$, then $(nm^{-1})^S = 1$, that is $nm^{-1}$ is in the subgroup generated by $g$, that is, $g^c = nm^{-1}$ for some integer $c$.

Then, for any member $e \in G_n$, we have $e = n \cdot g^a$ (for some $a$); we have $n \cdot g^a = n \cdot g^{-c} \cdot g^{a+c} = n \cdot n^{-1}m \cdot g^{a+c} = m \cdot g^{a+c}$, and hence $e \in G_m$.  Similarly, we can show that all elements $f \in G_m$ are also in $G_n$ and hence $G_n = G_m$

Extra credit for the reader: find the step where I implicitly assumed that $P$ was prime...

Comment: Thanks again. you are my hero answering that many questions. Some hint, those  $k_{m_i},  k_{n_i}$ should only be some random elements out of the set and not the sets themselves (edited top post, named them $G_n,G_m$). But that don't change anything. This finally destroyed my use case problem solving idea ([link](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/70282/how-safe-is-a-prime-with-p-2-cdot-q-cdot-r-cdot-s-cdot-t1-for-discrete-lo?rq=1)). For that case with 3 generators it should be $n^{QRS} \equiv m^{QRS} \mod P$